# Teamcity SSH Exec cannot execute command that I can if I login with Putty

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, teamcity, pm2

[image]

I can execute "pm2 restart next" totally fine if I login myself to the server and do it, and I can do it from anywhere. But, if I try to do the same thing with a Team City build using SSH Exec, and also using the same user I normally login with, it fails. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Had to run the command like this -> /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/pm2